# Swift: Multithreading Issue Getting Data From API

Tags: swift, multithreading

I'm having a problem where sometimes I can't successfully decode a json file due to a slow networking call. I have a list of stocks and I'm trying to successfully decode each one before the next stock gets decoded.

For example, I would have a list of 4 stocks but 3 would be successful decoded but 1 won't. The one that fails is also random. When I print out the url for the one that fails, the url and json file is correct yet I get an error of it not reading because its on a wrong format.

The list of stocks are retrieved through Firebase and after I receive them, I have a completion handler that tries to make a network call to the server. The reason why I added Firestore code here is because when I put a stop point at when case is successful, I notice that its hitting Thread 5 out of 14 Threads. Is having this many threads common? I know it's a threading issue but am having such a huge problem identifying where I should do dispatchGroups. Any help and clarifications would be much appreciated!

APIManager

```
private var stocks = [Stock]()

func getStockList( for symbols: [Stock], completion: ((Result<[Stock]>) -> Void)?) {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for symbol in symbols {
        var urlComponents = URLComponents()
        urlComponents.scheme = "https"
        urlComponents.host = APIManager.baseAPIURL
        urlComponents.path = "\(APIManager.baseRelativePath)/market/batch"

        //URL parameters
        let token = URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: "fakeToken")
        let symbolsItem = URLQueryItem(name: "symbols", value: symbol.symbol)

        let typesItem = URLQueryItem(name: "types", value: "quote")

        urlComponents.queryItems = [token, symbolsItem, typesItem]
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else { fatalError("Could not create URL from components") }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        dispatchGroup.enter()
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, err) in
                    guard err == nil else {
                        completion?(.failure(err!))
                        return
                    }

                    guard let jsonData = responseData else {
                        let err = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Data was not retrieved from request"]) as Error
                        completion?(.failure(err))
                        return
                    }

                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    do {
                        let data = try decoder.decode([String: Stock].self, from: jsonData)
                        let jsonData = data.map{ $0.value }
                        completion?(.success(jsonData))

                        dispatchGroup.leave()

                    } catch {
                        completion?(.failure(error))
                        print("Failed to decode using stock URL for \(symbol.symbol ?? ""): \n \(url)")
                    }
                }
            task.resume()
    }
}
```

HomeViewController

```
 class HomeViewController: UIViewController, LoginViewControllerDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchStocksFromFireStore(completion: { (stocks) -> Void in
        APIManager.shareInstance.getStockList(for: self.fetchedStocks) { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .success(let stocks):
                stocks.forEach { (stock) in
                    print("Company: \(stock.companyName ?? "")")
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
  }
}

func fetchStocksFromFireStore(completion: @escaping ([Stock]) -> ()) {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("stocks").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting stocks snapshot", err.localizedDescription)
            return

        } else {
            snapshot?.documents.forEach({ (snapshot) in
                var stock = Stock()
                stock.symbol = snapshot.documentID
                self.fetchedStocks.append(stock)
            })

            completion(self.fetchedStocks)

        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
struct Stock {
var symbol: String?
var companyName: String?
var latestPrice: Double?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case symbol
    case companyName
    case latestPrice
}

enum QuoteKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case quote
 }
}

extension Stock: Encodable {
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var quoteContainer = encoder.container(keyedBy: QuoteKeys.self)
    var quoteNestedValues = quoteContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .quote)
    try quoteNestedValues.encode(symbol, forKey: .symbol)
    try quoteNestedValues.encode(companyName, forKey: .companyName)
    try quoteNestedValues.encode(latestPrice, forKey: .latestPrice)
 }
}

extension Stock: Decodable {
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let quoteValues = try decoder.container(keyedBy: QuoteKeys.self)
    let quoteNestedValues = try quoteValues.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .quote)

    symbol = try quoteNestedValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .symbol)
    companyName = try quoteNestedValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .companyName)
    latestPrice = try quoteNestedValues.decode(Double.self, forKey: .latestPrice)
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the model? One really confusing thing i see is that you decode the full model as an array, loop through it to get all the values and then you loop through each object in the model to only fetch 1 value, why not only fetch that value from the beginning?

Comment: why are you using dispatch group ?

Comment: Vollan, I just edited it with the model attached. For the fetchStocksFromFirestore, I only get symbols, which I save as an array of stocks. GetStockList, then takes each of those and then decodes them. Once it's successful, I want to print each of them out. What do you mean by fetch all that value from the beginning? Isn't that what I'm doing by looping them? How would you do this?

Comment: JawadAli, I'm doing dispatch group because some the values weren't successfully decoded before it goes onto the next loop. I have 4 stocks, and only 3 gets decoded. The one that fails is always a random stock within that list. I felt that this was a threading issue. I'm using DispatchGroup to make sure that all have been successfully decoded before it moves on to the next. Is this not the right approach?